# web service session works while debugging but not when its published

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I'm finishing up my first web service. It stores data on a dataset that I later need to check up on, so I need to keep that information around.

I've already enabled the session in the web service's method "EnableSession = true"

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Receives status requests, as well as status udpates.", EnableSession = true)]
```

If I debug the web service everything works but if I try to use the application that sends the requests to the web service while it is published, the session keeps restarting again and again and again. Can anyone please tell me who do I have to kill to get this going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to setup a cookie container in the client:

```
var cookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
client.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

Comment: I added the code to the form_Load of my client's application but it's still losing the session. Also, the code would give me errors until I added "localhost.Service client = new localhost.Service();" which I didn't have before, I wonder if this is doing more harm than good.

Comment: I guess you set the cookie container just after creating the client

Comment: Please post a sample of you client code so we can help you. Anyway the CookieContainer is needed to consume a stateful WS.

Comment: My guess was right. I was assigning the cookieContainer to the wrong service. It's working now thanks to your code. thanx!